# copy chinese text from pdf that created with ios sdk CGPDFContextCreateWithURL(), found it is dismiss text when i paste！

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, encoding

I use IOS SDK CGPDFContextCreateWithURL() created pdf file，it is fine to read, but when i copy Chinese text from pdf and paste to Pages (apple text editor) or other text editor, i found it dismiss text. but if the copy text is English word it is fine. why ? it is a bug for CGPDFContextCreateWithURL() ? or the problem with encoding ？

Comment: Can you upload a sample PDF that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: you can download the sample PDF file from [link](http://oodkfs4lg.bkt.clouddn.com/ipad%E7%AB%AF%E5%AF%BC%E5%87%BA.pdf) ,thanks your guidance！

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be some sort of issue with the Ping Fang Smallcaps font in the PDF and CGPDFContext isn't able to overcome the issue. You can see below that Adobe Acrobat also has trouble extracting the text accurately. Foxit PhantomPDF can successfully extract the text.

## Adobe Acrobat

```
打发撒地⽅方阿斯蒂芬
fasdfd 1234567890
⼀一⼆二三四五六七⼋八九⼗十
```

## Foxit PhantomPDF

```
打发撒地⽅阿斯蒂芬
fasdfd 1234567890
⼀⼆三四五六七⼋九⼗
```

## Foxit PDF SDK

```
打发撒地⽅阿斯蒂芬
fasdfd 1234567890
⼀⼆三四五六七⼋九⼗
```

This isn't an uncommon scenario -- there are many malformed PDF files out in the wild and unfortunately it's often left up to PDF viewers to overcome these issues -- though it is unusual that the technology used to create the PDF (Quartz PDFContext) can't itself properly process the resulting PDF. It's unlikely you could repair the PDF manually.

Comment: thanks! but if i want to create a pdf files that can copy and paste  correctly to other TextEditor, since i can not use Quartz PDFContext to solve this problem, have other solution to create formed  pdf files ?